# An analog of the representation dimension for algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

The representation dimension of a finite dimensional algebra $A$ is defined as
$repdim(A)= \inf \{ gldim(B) | B=End_A(M)$ for a generator-cogenerator $M \}$.
It was shown by Iyama that it is always finite, answering a question of Auslander.

Define $urepdim(A)= \sup \{ gldim(B) | gldim(B) < \infty , B=End_A(M)$ for a generator-cogenerator $M \}$.

> Question 1: Is $urepdim(A)$ finite?
>
> Question 2: What is $urepdim(A)$ in case $A$ is hereditary (of Dynkin type)?

Define $frepdim(A)= \sup \{ findim(B) | B=End_A(M)$ for a generator-cogenerator $M \}$, where $findim(B)$ denotes the finitistic dimension of $B$.

> Question: Is $frepdim(A)$ finite?